# Challenge on Property of Complement in Language

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar, regular-language, turing-machines

We have:

[image]

and M be a finite automata.

Suppose d(M) be a deterministic automata that equivalence to M. if $M_1$ and  $M_2$ be two finite automata,  $M_1 +  M_2$ is the finite automata such that the language of this automata is the union of language $M_1$ and  $M_2$.

if  $G_1$ and  $G_2$  be two regular grammar such that language of these be $M_1$ and  $M_2$, how the author conclude:

$L(G_1)-L(G_2)=L(\overline{d(\overline{d(M_1)}+M_2))} $

is true.

my question is why for example the following false:

$L(G_1)-L(G_2)=L(\overline{\overline{d(M_1)}+\overline{d(M_2)}})$

I ran into another question why before complement we should deterministic the automat?

Comment: I don't understand your notation here.  If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are automata, what does $d(M_1)$ represent?  And what do you mean by "union of $M_1$ and $M_2$"?  I know how to take unions of languages, but the union of automata is not clear.

Comment: Dear @MJD, I edit my question?

Comment: What does $\overline{d(M_1)}$ mean? Is that supposed to be an automaton that accepts the complement of the language accepted by $d(M_1)$?

Comment: Dear @MJD, yes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example of how bad notation can make simple questions much more difficult.

(1) There is no reason to introduce grammars. You may as well denote by $L_1$ the language accepted by $M_1$ and by $L_2$ the language accepted by $M_2$.

(2) Let us denote by $L^c$ the complement of a language $L$. Then your first (correct) equality amounts to prove that $L_1 - L_2 = (L_1^c \cup L_2)^c$. Your second expression however would be $(L_1^c \cup L_2^c)^c = L_1 \cap L_2$.

As for your last question, you cannot directly compute an automaton accepting the complement of an automaton if you start with a nondeterministic automaton. Actually, there are known examples of a language with an $n$-state minimal DFA for which the minimal DFA of its complement has $2^n$ states.

Comment: Dear @pin, so why  $L(G_1)-L(G_2)=L(\overline{\overline{d(M_1)}+{d(M_2)}})$ is false?

Comment: Your definition is too imprecise: "if $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two finite automata, $M_1+M_2$ is the finite automata such that ..." Such an automaton is not unique, so your definition does not make sense. In particular if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are NFA's.

Comment: Dear pin. infact this is an recent quiz. I think this is not good question. I exact translate it. you means the above sentence in first comment is True or false? thanks again.

Comment: i think the firs comment is True, too.

Comment: Dear Pin, would you please correct me in first comment?

Comment: Dear @J.-E.Pin, would you please complete your answer to approve it?

Comment: You should first answer my comment if you want a precise answer. How do you define the $+$ operation and the $\overline{M}$ operation precisely ?

Comment: Dear Pin, I need you response to clarify my first comment :) thanks